# Specialize type in method that implements a generic interface method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method in an interface that I want to specialize the types for in classes that implement that interface. Something like this:

```
public interface Iface
{
    Function<Some, Some> Updater<T>(Func<T, T> op) where T : Iface;
}

public class Test : Iface
{
    public Function<Some, Some> Updater<T>(Func<T, T> op) where T : Test
    {
        // Use op with parameters that are of type Test
        return null;
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile of course. I know I could put a type param on Iface and get it to compile, but that gets messy and so I'm wondering if there is some way to do it without that. Is there some way just from the declarations of the methods in the interface and class that can make it so I can have the subclass work with it's own type but declare it in the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but adding a type param to the `Iface` is the only way that I think that you can do this.  Why do you think it is messy?

Here it is:

```
public interface Iface
{
    // TODO: Add non type specific methods here
}

public interface Iface<TIface> : Iface
    where TIface : Iface<TIface>
{
    // Type specific methods get defined here
    Function<Some, Some> Updater(Func<TIface, TIface> op);
}

public class Test : Iface<Test> // <- We're implementing the generic version of Iface<TIface> instead of Iface.  Note that Iface<TIface> extends Iface, so this class must implement that interface too.
{
    public Function<Some, Some> Updater(Func<Test, Test> op)
    {
        // Use op with parameters that are of type Test
        return null;
    }
}
```

It looks less messy to me.

**Updated**

I added a base `Iface` interface without the generics type parameter for the places where the type parameter is not needed.

Comment: It just seems redundant since `Test : Iface<Test>`--we already know it's a Test why need to say it again? And with a number of implementing classes, having to propagate them. Anyway, not a big deal, just wondering if there was something more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: And as for messiness... I use Iface all over the place. Making it generic makes that propagate all throughout the codebase and making it very hard to deal with. Especially in places where I don't care which Iface it is (and C# doesn't have wildcards for generics).

Comment: @taotree In the places where you don't care about which Iface you are dealing with, are there methods on Iface that you are trying to use?

Comment: @taotree You have to say Test again in the class signature, because `Iface<TIface>` cannot know that `TIface` is `Test`.  I have a CRTP/F-bound proposal out on the Roslyn github site that may be able to address this with a tweak to the proposed syntax to imply the subclass type argument.  You may want to go comment on it.  You can find the proposal here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4332

Comment: @taotree Another reason that you have to specify `Test : Iface<Test>` is due to the very change I just made to the answer.  What if there is another actual `Iface` that does not take a type parameter in addition to the one that does.  How is the compiler to resolve which to implement between `Iface` and `Iface<TIface>`?